# Prove that the smallest eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix $A$ is equal to the minimum value of $u^TAu$ where $u$ is a unit vector in $\Bbb R^n$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $D = \{u \in \mathbb{R}^n | \|u\|=1\}$ denote the unit sphere.

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric matrix, and denote its smallest eigenvalue by $\lambda_\min$. Why do we have

$$\lambda_\min =\min_{u \in D} u^TAu?$$

I don't quite get what the minimum imply in this statement, does it mean that the smallest unit vector $u$ or smallest value of $u^TAu$ given $u$ is a unit vector?

Comment: I means the $\min$ of the expression $u^T Au$ taken over all $u$ such that $\|u\| = 1$.

Comment: That expression means "the smallest value uf $u^TAu$ when looking at all $u\in D.$

Comment: See the answer to the inverse question https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3357310/704255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;\lambda_1\le\ldots\le\lambda_n\;$ be the eigenvalues of $\;A\;$ , and let $\;\{v_1,...,v_n\}\;$ be an orthonormal basis of corresponding eigenvectors of $\;A\;$. Let us denote by $\;(,)\;$ the usual inner product in $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ .

Thus, if we take  $\;x=\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_kv_k\in\Bbb R^n\;$ , then we get (all this stuff is around the spectral theorem. Check this important theorem) for the quadratic form $\;q(x):=x^tAx\;$ the following:

$$q(x)=x^tAx=(Ax,x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_ka_k^2\ge\lambda_1\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2=\lambda_1\left\|x\right\|^2$$

The above is true for any $\;x\in\Bbb R^n\;$ and then also for any unit vector there. Finally, observe that

$$\lambda_1=\lambda_1\left\|v_1\right\|=\lambda_1(v_1,v_1)=v_1^tAv_1$$

...and of course $\;v_1\;$ is a unit vector. Now fill up details and finish the argument (there's hardly anything left)

Comment: Is there always an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors? Why?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Because the matrix is (real) symmetric. Spectral Theorem. This is the same as saying that A can be orthogonally diagonalized.

Comment: Oh, of course, $\lambda_i\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=\langle Av_i,v_j\rangle =\langle v_i,Av_j\rangle=\lambda_j\langle v_i,v_j\rangle$ so either either $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$ or the vectors are normal, and we can find an orthonormal basis of the subspace of eigenvectors of any individual $\lambda_i.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yup. I'm pretty sharp at this now as I've just lectured the course linear algebra II at university...:)