# How to minimise given function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization

> Let a is fixed $f:R^{n^2}\times R^n\to R$ such that $f(A,u)=u^TAu+a^Ta$ where $A$ is a symmetric, invertible matrix. Find $u$ such that $f$ attains the minimum for that $A$.

I know that suppose f attain minima then at that point partial derivative is o

$f_u=2u^TA$ its partial derivative

as A is invertible implies $u=\bar 0$

So mimima occur at 0.

But is it possible to find unit vector that minimises f?

That is I wanted to find unit vector u such that for any unit vector v $f(u)\leq f(v)$?

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Surely it should be $F:\Bbb R^{n^2}\times\Bbb R^\color{blue}{n}\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Dear Sir WHy there is no minimum in case of A is negative definite Please Can you illustrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left\{\begin{array} . f \to \min\limits_{u} \\
s.t. \ u^T u = 1
 \end{array} \right. $

Let's use the Lagrangian: $L = u^T A u + a^Ta - \lambda \cdot (u^Tu - 1)$. Necessary condition of minimum - $\nabla_{u} L = 0$.

$\nabla_{u} L = 2Au - 2\lambda u = 0  \Rightarrow Au = \lambda u \Rightarrow$ u should be the (normilized) eigenvector, corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue of matrix A.